# Galaxy S10e phone call quality on receiver's end poor, but otherwise all is fine

Tags: samsung, audio, calls, microphone, samsung-galaxy-s-10

When making a phone call on my Galaxy S10e (Exynos), the audio for the receiver is quite low, chopped and sounds a bit like being underwater. I've confirmed this with echo test calls - it always happens.

However, audio calls via WhatsApp or plain sound recording are working perfectly. The only thing affected is a real phone call.

Tried clearing all cache for all phone related apps and services. Tried Android's safe mode ... Tried at different locations. To no avail.

It's like the microphone is set on a very low sensitivity, but I see no way of controlling that.

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Could be a problem of your mobile provider. Mobile networks mostly use different audio codecs than used in wired telephone networks, so any call that leaves the MNO network may be converted to a different format which can cause problems.